# Is given sentence is correct

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

One of my friend told one sentence

> Bruh I gotta go to grab some booze

Is this correct?

Comment: Why no one answering my question?

Comment: I think you're not getting any answers because we can't understand what you're trying to ask. What's happening two times?

Comment: [*I have got to go to work tomorrow*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22have+got+to+go+to+work%22) is perfectly natural English, as shown by numerous written instances in that link. But ***Bruh I gotta go*** would certainly get marked down in any "teaching" environment.

Comment: In order to know if the sentence is correct, we need to know your friend's reasons - why does he gotta grab booze? If the answer is "to supply booze for a party" then perhaps it is correct. If the answer is "to have a drink" then no, he is incorrect - he could just grab water instead.

Answer (score 1):

The quoted text is very informal.

"Bruh" is informal. It means "brother."  Usually it's an attention getting symbol rather than containing any actual information. You can leave it out if you like. If you are speaking informally you can include it. If it really is your brother you are speaking to you can say "brother."

"Gotta" is informal for "got to," which is also informal and means "have to" or "must" or "need to."

In context, "to grab" means to get. Possibly to buy at a store, or possibly to get from the refrigerator.

"Booze" means "alcoholic beverage." It is a generic term meaning any kind of alcohol.

And, you are missing punctuation.

So putting it all together, you could write something like one of the following.

> Brother, I need to go buy some wine.
>
> I need to get another beer from the fridge.

Either of these announcements is typical when you want the listener to indicate if they want you to pick up something for them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is that particular sentence correct or not?

Comment: Depends what you call 'correct'. Someone might say that when using very informal language.